# Custom Number Format from UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform, number-formatting

I've got a text box in a user form where the user puts unit (for example "kg"). I am trying to use this unit to format number of a cell (to add the unit after the value in a cell)

```
Sub Custom_unit()

Dim Cust_un As String

Cust_un = IM_Form1.TextBox1.Value
Selection.NumberFormat = "0" & Cust_un

End Sub
```

This is my attempt but when I try to run it, I get a Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to add quotes to `NumberFormat`**

Given an input from a textbox, you get a string value, e.g. "kg".
In order to use that as a NumberFormat suffix 
you need to enclose the unit string with quotes.

You could do that by assigning

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0" & """" & Cust_un & """"
```

or alternatively

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0" & Chr(34) & Cust_un & Chr(34)
```

Note that VBA can neither interprete a single quote (`"`) as string, 
nor a single quote enclosed by a start and end quote (`"""`). 
Yyou have to include a pair of quotes within the surrounding quotes instead, i.e. `""""` to make it understood.
The alternative uses the `Chr()` function 
returning a string containing the character associated with the specified character code 34, i.e. the double quote character.

You might prefer to use a help function to return the correct NumberFormat, such as

```
Function getNumberFormat(ByVal unit As String, Optional NumFmt As String = "0 ") As String
    unit = Replace(unit, Chr(34), vbNullString)         ' remove existing double quotes
    getNumberFormat = NumFmt & Chr(34) & unit & Chr(34) ' build NumberFormat including quotes around unit
    ' or: getNumberFormat = NumFmt & """" & unit & """"
End Function
```

**Example call**

Assuming your `Custom_unit()` procedure resides in the `UserForm` code module use `Me.TextBox1.Text` to refer to the current UserForm instance instead of referring to the default instance of the userform. An example call could be as follows:

```
Sub Custom_unit()
    Selection.NumberFormat = getNumberFormat(Me.TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

BTW a hint: in most cases it's better to avoid selection references, c.f. [How to avoid using Select in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/28700020?r=SearchResults&s=2|22.3466#28700020)